# PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event preventing Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a button binded to a command like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyCommand, ElementName=MyWindow}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

And I'm using the Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown to open a confirm window with this code

```
private void CopyButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(Resources.Strings.MessageBox,
                            Resources.Strings.ConfirmOperationMessageBox,
                            MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxImage.Question,
                            MessageBoxResult.Yes) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

This work fine to stop the command from been called, but even if the MessageBoxResult is yes, somehow the command never get called.

A simple workaroud that I'm currently using is to add a MyCommand.Execute in the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler but I don't really like putting a reference to the ViewModel in the code behind.

I was wondering if there is a better solution for what I'm trying to achieve or if anyone knows why the event stops the command from been called.

Comment: Do you have tried to force e.Handled = false in the else clause of the IF ?

Try to call the base implementation: base.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(this, e);

Comment: Yes, I've tried e.Handled = false, it doesn't work either. Now I'm trying to call the base implementation as you said, but base.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown allows only += assignation and doesn't provide the method you pointed out.

Comment: I tested it with e.Handled = false and the command get's called. Are you sure the command binding is OK? Have you tried removing the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and check if it's called?